# Unit testing functions calling other tested functions

Tags: design, unit-testing, dry

I have three functions:

- `ValidateUsername()`, which determines if a string is a valid username according to some rules
- `SetUsername()` which sets a string as a user's Username if it passes validation
- `AddNewUser()`, which creates a new user and, among others, sets a string as his or hers Username using `SetUsername()`

All three should fail if the supplied username string is incorrect, yet `ValidateUsername()` is where the rules reside. How would I unit test this? Testing validation only in `ValidateUsername()` leaves the possibility that someone will mistakenly omit validation and set the username directly in `AddNewUser()`. On the other hand, repeating all different validation test cases for all functions seems counterproductive. What's the best practice?

Comment: see also: [How to manage success dependency between unit tests](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/224829/how-to-manage-success-dependency-between-unit-tests)

Comment: Are these methods all on the same class?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unit testing is called that way because you are intending to test units of work, in your case each method is a unit of work and not the whole integration between them.

Let's assume your business requirement for ValidateUsername() method is to validate the user name according to certain requirements. Your unit test in this case should verify that validation was correct and rules are implemented correctly.

Now seems like for you other methods,  one of the business requirements is to call validation method - do just that. Ensure that the ValidateUsername was called indeed. You don't care whether it was executed correctly or not - that part is to be tested by your previous test for ValidateUsername unit.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up mocking the validating class containing the validation method to check if it was called. This seemed practical as I want all validation logic to live inside it.

Comment: Well done, Mocking is what needed to do :)

Comment: Just be careful though as mocking will only test that the `SetUsername` function called the `ValidateUsername` function but not that it (`SetUsername`) then did anything with that result... it could have just ignored it.  If the `SetUsername` function is touching a datastore you could test the correct value is stored.  For the `AddNewUser`, you can test the function/API returns an error or returns a new user with the validated/corrected user name.

Answer (score 4):

You can verify that the validation function was called by testing the other two functions with one invalid name and one valid name. Or you can separate the logic into UsernameValidator and UserService, and inject the validator into the user service. Then you test the user service by mocking the validator.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, `AddNewUser()` calls `SetUsername()`, and `SetUsername()` calls `ValidateUsername()`. Two options come to mind:

1) Keep the existing structure, and write unit tests for the "one thing" that each function is responsible for, while assuming the "happy path" for its dependencies. So the `ValidateUsername()` tests would check valid and invalid usernames, the `SetUsername()` test would pass in a valid username and make sure that username ends up in the right place, and the `AddNewUser()` test would pass in valid user-construction data and make sure a user got added using that data.

2) Change the structure to something "flatter" so that the functions no longer depend on each other. So you might have a `AttemptToAddUser()` function that calls `ValidateUsername()`, then `SetUsername()`, then `AddNewUser()` all at the same level of the call stack.

The optimal answer depends heavily on your exact code, but I would expect it to be either #1 or something between #1 and #2. It might make perfect sense to pull `ValidateUsername()` up to the same level as `AddNewUser()`, but I have a hard time imagining a `SetUsername()` function being of any use outside the `AddNewUser()` function (assuming it's not a method on a User object or something).

And of course, regardless of how the unit tests work, you probably still want a small number of integration tests that check all of these functions together.

Comment: Option (1) would not test all relevant code-paths of `SetUsername()` and `AddNewUser()`. Option (2) calls for bad coding habits (copy-and-pasting idioms). I don't like either.